# Hyphens in variable values (in bash)

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple script for **iptables** to restrict access using MAC addresses.
First, I check if an address has been passed to the script:

```
ALLOWED_MAC=$5
MAC_STRING=""
if [ -n "$ALLOWED_MAC" ] ; then
    MAC_STRING="-m mac --mac-source ${ALLOWED_MAC}"
fi
```

Then I pass the `MAC_STRING`variable to **iptables**:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT $MAC_STRING -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I could (of course) have if/else'ed the whole thing but this solution look cleaner. If the user specifies an MAC address if gets passed on to **iptables**, otherwise we just pass an empty string.

However, when I run this script I get an error from **iptables**:

```
iptables v1.4.9.1: Invalid match name " mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55" (28 chars max)
```

The hyphen/dash/minus before the `m` from `MAC_STRING` has disappeared. But if I instead echo the intended command everything look right:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80  -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I've tried this with other commands as well but with the same result; if I have a variable value starting with a hypen it gets gobbled when passed as a parameter to a program.

Comment: have you tried scapping the "-" with slashes? \-\- ?

Comment: The `-` is there all right - it's told `iptables` that what follows is a match name, and the rest of the variable is being treated as the match name. You didn't use any quotes in your command, but the effect is as if you did.

Comment: vfbsilva: Yes, I've tried escaping but then `\m´ is passed instead (which of course is wrong).

Comment: And just to be clear: if I run the "produced" command (with the evaluated MAC string) in my terminal it works great.

Comment: As muru pointed out; **iptables** seems to accept the `-m` parameter but but breaks on the `mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55` part.

Comment: @user1143242 are you sure you didn't quote `$MAC_STRING` in the iptables command?

Comment: Yep, the command it is: `iptables -A INPUT -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT $MAC_STRING -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

The only quotes are where I set its values (at the top).

Comment: (1) What’s the she-bang line in your script?  (2) Please create a script: `#!/bin/sh` (newline) `printf "%d args:" $#; printf " <%s>" "$@"; echo`, call it `args`, and run `./args $MAC_STRING` (optionally, with `-A INPUT -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT` before `$MAC_STRING`) both from your terminal command line and from your script (and post the output in your question).

Comment: Please post a complete script that reproduces the problem. It looks like you've changed `IFS` but we can't tell without seeing the script

Comment: @gilles: Yes, I've changed IFS to `IFS=";"` but didn't think that would matter in this case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the entire script, without it, all we can do is guess. The question can be reopened once you have added details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out thanks to @Gilles who pointed me in the right direction.

The iptables/mac snippet is inside a function. In my script I iterate over a given set of files and parse them, and then invoke the iptables function (for each file).

As it turns out I'm changing the `IFS`at the top of the script (to simplify the file parsing) and let it be changed for the rest of the script.
But if I start by saving the old `IFS` value and then set it back to this (old value) before each invocation everything works as expected!

So, this **doesn't** work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function allow()
{
    [variable defs] 

    if [ -n "$ALLOWED_MAC" ] ; then
        MAC_STRING="-m mac --mac-source $ALLOWED_MAC"
    fi

    iptables -A INPUT -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT $MAC_STRING -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
}

#Set the Internal Field Separator to the token used in the files.
IFS=";"

[variable defs]

#Iterate over all the port files.
for file in $FILES
do

#Read the first (and only) line from the current file and split the tokens into an array.
LINE="$(cat $file)"
set -- "$LINE" 
declare -a Tokens=($*) 

[parse tokens]

#Call 'allow' for each port definition.
allow $PROTOCOL $PORT $DIRECTION $ALLOWED_MAC

done
```

But this works perfectly:

```
#!/bin/bash

function allow()
{
    [variable defs]

    if [ -n "$ALLOWED_MAC" ] ; then
        MAC_STRING="-m mac --mac-source $ALLOWED_MAC"
    fi

    iptables -A INPUT -p $PROTOCOL --dport $PORT $MAC_STRING -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
}

#Save the "original" IFS
OLD_IFS=$IFS

[variable defs]

#Iterate over all the port files.
for file in $FILES
do

#Set the Internal Field Separator to the token used in the files.
IFS=";"

#Read the first (and only) line from the current file and split the tokens into an array.
LINE="$(cat $file)"
set -- "$LINE" 
declare -a Tokens=($*) 

[parse tokens]

#Reset IFS before invoking the function.
IFS=$OLD_IFS

#Call 'allow' for each port definition.
allow $PROTOCOL $PORT $DIRECTION $ALLOWED_MAC

done
```

I might have missed something during copy/paste into here but I'm hoping that the essentials are there.

Thanks for your help!

//Anders